# Create Mocks For TypeAlias with composition of Protocols using Sourcery

Tags: ios, swift, sourcery

I was wondering if it is possible to generate mocks for Associated types using Sourcery!

```
protocol A {
}

protocol B {
}

/// sourcery: AutoMockable
typealias C = A & B
```

If I try this nothing happens and due to this I've to create my mocks by my own, its weird though it should have work, any workaround or solution for this?